# Difference between EXTRACT(year from timestamp) function and date_part('year', timestamp) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostreSQl server and have to get data grouped by date part of timestamp (ie. group by month or year or week) so I am using the `Extract(year from timestamp)` function but I saw in the Postgresql documentation that there is a function `date_part('year',timestamp)` too which can do the same. Here I confused which function I have to use and which function will be efficient. Also please tell me if there is another good way to get data groped by date part.

Comment: Can you include the query you are using?

Comment: Hi Tim,
I am using the query is :
select  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date(ticket.transactiondate)),(round(cast(sum(ticketitem.netprice)as NUMERIC(36,2)), 2)) as grandTotal,count(ticketitem.id) as noOfItem,count(distinct ticket.id)as kpi from ticket INNER JOIN ticketitem on ticket.id=ticketitem.ticketid where (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date(ticket.transactiondate))='7' or EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date(ticket.transactiondate))='6') and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date(ticket.transactiondate))='2015' group by 1 order by 1 asc

Thank you!!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

They are both the same.

In fact `extract()` gets re-written to `date_part()` - check the execution plan and you will see.

`extract()` complies with the SQL standard, `date_part()` is a Postgres specific query. As one gets converted to the other, there is absolutely no performance difference. If you prefer to write standard SQL, stick to `extract()`

Update 2021-12-16

Starting with Postgres 14 this is no longer the case, the implementation is now different:

The [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.0/) state:

> Change `EXTRACT()` to return type numeric instead of float8 (Peter Eisentraut).
> This avoids loss-of-precision issues in some usages. The old behavior can still be obtained by using the old underlying function date_part().

Comment: Do you mean `date_part`?

Comment: @EugenKonkov: yes, indeed. Thanks

Comment: `In fact extract() gets re-written to date_part()` - Not any more! Compare [9.6](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=44f497752db36630de2abb55b90ab69a) (up  to 13.4), **but** [14.1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=44f497752db36630de2abb55b90ab69a)! Not sure why this is the case...  Googled - got nothing!

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW: there is an entry in the release notes. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I quote the answer from Postgresql.org

> Blockquote
>   The EXTRACT syntax ends up as a call to the internal date_part(...) 
>   function. If SQL-portability is not a concern, calling date_part()
>   directly should be a bit quicker.

[Reference Link](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20011129094839.GB11369%40rcfile.org)

Comment: Not any more - see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442340/difference-between-extractyear-from-timestamp-function-and-date-partyear-t#comment124403278_38444997).